# Error: Caused by error: ! `DEPGDS_FIRST` must be size 9 or 1, not 0

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this. I want to capture the first GDS score when GDS >= 5 as GDS_FIRST. If none of the GDS scores from each visit are bigger than 5, return 0. If GDS is missing data in every visit for a person, then return NA. The same person has the same GDS_FIRST in every row.

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3) 
Visit <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3) 
GDS <- c(0,2,5,6,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,6,5) 
df <- data.frame(ID, Visit, GDS)
```

My new column GDS_FIRST would look like:
GDS_FIRST <- c(5,5,5,5,5,NA,NA,NA,6,6,6)

I tried the code below it gave me an error message. I think it's because ID==3 only has missing data?

```
df %>%
group_by (ID) %>%
mutate(GDS_FIRST = GDS[which.max(GDS >=5)])
```

It says:
Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `GDS_FIRST = GDS[which.max(NACCGDS >= 5)]`.
ℹ In group 236: `ID = "3"`.
Caused by error:
! `GDS_FIRST` must be size 3 or 1, not 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gives your stated expected result:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(GDS_FIRST = if(!all(is.na(GDS)) & any(GDS > 5)) {
    first(GDS[GDS >= 5 & !is.na(GDS)]) 
    } else if(all(is.na(GDS))) NA else 0, .by = ID)
#>    ID Visit GDS GDS_FIRST
#> 1   1     1   0         5
#> 2   1     2   2         5
#> 3   1     3   5         5
#> 4   1     4   6         5
#> 5   1     5   5         5
#> 6   2     1  NA        NA
#> 7   2     2  NA        NA
#> 8   2     3  NA        NA
#> 9   3     1  NA         6
#> 10  3     2   6         6
#> 11  3     3   5         6
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I want the first GDS score >=5. Sorry I didn't say that clearly.

Comment: @Jenn0804 Ah, now I understand. See my update

Comment: Thank you! However, in my real data set, some people have NA in one of their visits then this code won't work. See my updated data

Comment: @Jenn0804 in that case, we can change `first(GDS[GDS >= 5])` to `first(GDS[GDS >= 5 & !is.na(GDS)])`. See my update.